# Excel Lookups Multiple Columns Concatenated

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vlookup

I have a spreadsheet like this:

```
| hostname | key  | value |
| host1   | tagA | abc   |
| host1   | tagB | bcd   |
| host1   | tagC | efg   |
| host2   | tagB | hij   |
| host3   | tagB | jkl   |
```

Elsewhere, I have a single cell: `host1`. In the following cell, I want to lookup the **value** for, say **host1 tag C**.

That is to say, I want to end up with this:

```
host 1 | efg
```

If I my lookup fails, it should output something like this (eg. looking up value for `tagA of host2`):

```
host2 | #N/A
```

I've tried using `VLOOKUP` but I'm getting a `#REF!` error:

[[image: ]1]]

Comment: Try to use SUMPRODUCT function.

Answer (score 1):

the table range in your VLOOKUP function is incorrectly. Change the table range  and the column to return to:

```
=VLOOKUP("host1tagB",A1:D5,4,FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this without a helper column, if you prefer:

[image]